# Minecraft Server Questions--VTC?

Tags: discussion, close-reasons

I'm honestly confused as to whether I should be VTCing these or not.  I'm looking at them and trying to decide if they refer to technology that's useful outside of Minecraft servers or not, and using that as a basis.  (Minecraft is clearly not a "reasonable business information technology" topic, but GRE tunnels are.)  But we do close questions referring to home and dev environments with extreme prejudice, regardless of whether or not the technology is otherwise business tech, so I think I'm wrong.  :)

This question inspired by:

- [Port Forwarding through a GRE Tunnel](https://serverfault.com/questions/663259/port-forwarding-through-a-gre-tunnel)
- [GRE Tunnel Collapsing in One Direction](https://serverfault.com/questions/663277/gre-tunnel-collapsing-in-one-direction)

They're both otherwise reasonable questions, hence my indecision.  I almost talked myself into VTCing writing this up.  ;)

(If we still had "Professional System Administration" rather than "Reasonable Business Information Technology" as a close reason, I'd VTC them both.)

Comment: You could suggest moving them over to [Arqade](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/) if they get too gamey for you.  Just remember, game server hosting is a business as well.

Comment: I don't see how these are _Minecraft Server_ questions. Reading them I would consider the first one a routing question. And the second one I would rather close or comment on, as there not being enough information about the setup to really ascertain anything on the problem.

Comment: @Reaces Haha, I edited out the reference to Minecraft in the first one.  The second referred to the first.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Do whatever you want, really.

We've basically all saved a good home or dev environment question that we liked by editing out the home or dev environment part, and I see no reason to treat minecraft server questions any differently.

If you want to save them, save them, if you want to ignore them, ignore them, and if you're in a bad mood and feel like kicking a puppy through a barbed wire fence, VTC them and leave a comment threatening to kick the OP's puppy through a barbed wire fence.  Just makes sure you threaten *nicely*, on account of the *be-nice* policy on Stack Exchange.

Comment: LOL!  I may edit them as a random act of kindness, then.  :)  Thanks!

Comment: P.S.  OMG SAVE TEH PUPPIEZ!!!!!!!!!!!  ;)

Comment: pink-and-fluffy!!!

Comment: `...We've basically all saved a good home or dev environment question that we liked...` +1, but when did @hopeless get all soft hearted?

Comment: @BigHomie  Weird.  I don't usually get described as getting soft-hearted when I talk about kicking puppies through barbed wire.

Answer (score 5):

While it's possible to "save" them (as HopelessN00b points out), like many questions that we try to save these can fall back off the rails again quickly. I voted to migrate [this](https://superuser.com/questions/871156/setting-up-srv-records-for-minecraft-with-cloudflare) Minecraft question because the OP replied to an answer with *"Still wont allow me to connect through. Any ideas?"*.

While the OP was running a server business according to his own statements, that was definitely a comment soliciting advice for troubleshooting a game. Even if the server is being used for business related purposes, this SE's target audience is not appropriate for troubleshooting a game at the network level. :) At that point a migration is *helping* the question by giving it a better audience.

Comment: True! questions going off the rails is hardly limited to game servers.  I had a SQL Server question turn into "plz gimme teh codez" recently, for example, and SQL Server is clearly business software.  (I could have voted to migrate it to dba, but I don't think they want to give him the codes, either.)